# Making Twitter Bootstrap fixed width below 1024px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make it so Twitter Bootstrap doesn't go on responsive mode when I hit a resolution below 1024px. In other words, I want the horizontal sidebar to show up and not touch my rows or columns.

I have some conditionals with higher resolutions that I manage to achieve using the online LESS compiler, so I assume this can be done.

Which flag will I have to modify in order to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help to avoid responsiveness on smart phones and tablets.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
```

Also remove `initial-scale=1`and other values.

Add a container for everything, and set a min-width.

```
<style>
  .page-container {
    min-width: 1024px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="page-container">
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably posting much too late, but I was also attempting to do the same thing. If you follow [these instructions via Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive) you will have a layout that stops being responsive below 1024px.

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap docs have a [guide for disabling responsiveness](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive).

> 1. Omit the viewport `<meta>` mentioned in the CSS docs
> 2. Override the `width` on the `.container` for each grid tier with a single width, for example `width: 970px !important;` Be sure that this comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the `!important` with media queries or some selector-fu.
> 3. If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior.
> 4. For grid layouts, use `.col-xs-*` classes in addition to, or in place of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid scales to all resolutions.